# How to estimate the cost for creating a device for test purposes

Tags: pic

I have an idea of an electronic device, some kind of a gadget. It will have a bluetooth chip, some memory in it, some led indicators and some controlling chips, not sure yet how it should be constructed. What I need now is to estimate an approximate cost of the gadget hardware itself including the board, chips and the plastic case. What is a good way to calculate the cost?

Comment: Development time is going to be 80-90% of the cost.

Comment: Are you wanting to estimate what it will costs to re-manufacture or the cost of development, redesign, and bug fixing?

Comment: I would like to calculate the price for remanufacturing the device using an existing developed construction. I need it to have a picture of how much this gadget would cost if manufactured in large amounts so that to know if its worth that.

Comment: You already have a completed design, then? Seems the only thing left to do is add everything up and get quotes, then.

Comment: What is "large amounts" unless you talking 10,000+ the NRE costs will be significant.  You need FCC/CE certification, your doing RF design at 2.4Ghz, etc.  You could drop $100,000 pretty fast if you had an engineering firm do the design work.

Comment: How much is "large amounts"? This could be interpreted as 50, 500, 5,000, or 50,000+, depending on who you talk to.

Answer (score 3):

A ballpark figure for the manufacturing cost can be obtained by multiplying the parts cost by 3 to 5.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I use for estimates, they are not accurate by any means be at least gives me an idea:

- $0.50 per part to be soldered
- $300-$400 for a PCB order under a quantity of 100. Divide by the number of boards you want to get the cost per board
- If you already know what parts you are using, add up their cost
- Add on an extra buffer to account for all of the stuff you haven't thought of

Comment: Disagree with point #2, I got a quantity of 10x 2-layer PCBs for $40 USD total and 10x 4-layer for $150 USD total.

Comment: @Thomas O Can you tell me where you got those prices? Did they include soldermask and silkscreen"? Was there any student discount with that?

Comment: @Kellenjb, SeeedStudio and a few other places. 2-layer FR4, green soldermask (+$10 for red/blue/yellow soldermask), silkscreen on both sides, works with 6/6 mil rules. (8/8 for inner layers on 4-layer.)

Comment: your not tossing a 2.4Ghz RF transceiver (bluetooth) on a 2 layer FR-4 board and getting an operational device, at least not unless you really know what your doing and using specific types of antennas

Comment: @Mark I use a bluetooth module that has the antenna on board. In a situation like that a 2 layer is just fine. But yes, a bluetooth ic with your own antenna is a bit more difficult to do on 2 layers.

Comment: @kellenjb Yes obviously if your using a module thats fine.  If your just plopping a device on the board, thats the issue.  One of the reasons many use things like bluetooth in a module form is that RF PCB substrate is expensive and so they only want to use it for sections of the circuit that require it.  You may be able to get away with in with FR-4 if your were very careful in your PCB stack up and had the manufacturer impedance match the traces in post processing.  Doing that with a 2 layer board would be near impossible unless the PCB fab could make strange board thicknesses.

Comment: I should probably add that FR4 is just a designation, and there are many materials that fall under that designation.  You can get substrates that are still "FR4" that will operate up to 10-15Ghz but the stuff cheap PCB fabs use by default (what i'm referring to in this context) and call FR4 is generally good up to about 1Ghz depending on trace length.  The dielectric losses and propagation delays for frequencies past that get unmanageable.

Comment: @Thomas O Places like SeeedStudio, batchpcb, etc. are not really designed for the production stage of a product.

Comment: @Kellenjb - I also disagree with the $300-$400 number, but only because it implies that prototyping will be this expensive.  To get a few boards for testing will probably be much less. (<100, or much less if you're willing to wait for BatchPCB/Dorkbot/Seeedstudio etc.), but I'd agree that several panels will probably run about that much.   Try 4PCB's $33 each (2 layer) or $66 (4 layer) deals as well.

Comment: @reemrevnivek he said he is specifically looking for a price for manufacturing in large quantities. If anything I should have given numbers for larger quantities.

Comment: @Kellenjb - My thoughts exactly!  In my opinion/line of work, <100 is not 'large quantities'.   If you can estimate the cost as being always $300-$400, what you're getting is the setup costs, and that's not a useful metric.  I'd go with a number closer to $0.15 per square inch for large quantities of 2-layer boards, which seems to be fairly consistent from manufacturer to manufacturer.  You'll need to buy >$1,000 worth of PCB for prices in that range, i.e. the setup/shipping costs will have to be removed from the equation.

Comment: Eh? Is it really that hard to do RF on FR-4? 63 mil microstrip into an inverted f antenna, easy peasy?

Comment: @krapht yep that would work, assuming that a PCB antenna works for the application and the chip to antenna distance can be minimized.  Given that we have no idea if those requirement can be met we don't really know.  And again, we don't know what 'FR-4' material we're talking about...

Answer (score 2):

Parts cost is all about volumes. If you're making a handful, go with the prices on Farnell/Digikey/Mouser/etc. and buy from there.

If you're making in even modest quantities, you need to get on the phone with suppliers and request quotes.

As others have said, accurately predicting manufacturing costs is also hard.

Answer (score 1):

Estimating project cost is an art. It can be guesstimated by kludging together development time, parts and manufacturing cost. Time really is money, so the first thing to do is break down how long each part of the development cycle is going to take, **then multiply by 3X.** Only you know how much your time is worth -- I go by 5CAD/hr-15CAD/hr for personal projects, 25CAD/hr-50CAD/hr for contract work (experienced EE's use 100-200/hr). As [Leon mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8807/how-to-estimate-the-cost-for-creating-a-device-for-test-purposes/8809#8809), multiply parts cost by ~3X for manufacturing, including enclosure.